# Como fazer uma função esperar uma outra função que tem um subscribe com observable dentro?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-6, sincronização

Seguinte, Tenho uma função que gera um PDF, essa função pega um array montado e monta uma página. 
Após isso ela solicita a próxima página para o backend através de uma função com um subscribe.

Meu problema é que a função não espera, o typescript não segue um fluxo linear no código.

Segue uma representação em blocos funcionais para melhor entendimento.

```
geratePDF() {
  this.GetList();
  this.DesenhaPag();
  this.Page = this.Page ++; 
  this.GetList();
  this.DesenhaPag();
}
```

Aqui minha função com subscribe.

```
GetList() {
this.subcription = this.chipservice.listarChip(dadospagechip).subscribe(
  (response) => {

    const listChips = this.chipservice.Validate(response);
    this.montaArraychip(listChips[1], listChips[2]);
    this.subcription.unsubscribe();

  });
}

listarChip(listpage:ListChipsInteface):Observable<any> {
    const token: LoginInteface = this.authService.GetToken();
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.api}/api/user/ChipListHistory/`,[token ,chipvalue])
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Preciso de alguma forma segurar a geratePDF até a GetList terminar de Montar o Array.

Tentei com Promisse não consegui, 
Minha melhor solução até agora foi com  async, await e sleep, mas não ficou uma solução ruim, pois não sei ao certo quanto tempo demora a resposta.

Como seria a solução ideal?

Comment: voce pode usar o operador mergeMap ou switchMap

Comment: Você pode utilizar o switchMap do rxjs e encadear as chamadas dos observables.
Nesse [link](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-encadear-observables-67871) tem um exemplo de como fazer esse encadeamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Subject, ficaria alguma coisa assim:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


private listReady = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.otherSubscription = this.listReady.subscribe(
    () => {
        this.DesenhaPag();
        this.Page = this.Page ++; 
        this.DesenhaPag();
    }
  );
}

GetList() {
this.subcription = this.chipservice.listarChip(dadospagechip).subscribe(
  (response) => {

    const listChips = this.chipservice.Validate(response);
    this.montaArraychip(listChips[1], listChips[2]);
    this.subcription.unsubscribe();

    // aqui sinaliza que está pronto
    this.listReady.next('ready'); // pode ser qualquer objeto como parametro

  });
}

geratePDF() {
  this.GetList();
}
```